# Jquery handle two input fields with same id, same name and same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where inputs are dynamically generated two input fields with the same  id, same name  and same value.

User can then change any value in one of these two similar inputs (ie for example firstname).
How can i check if the values in the two input fields are the same, if they are same then just submit the first input and if not the same then submit the changed value.

so final submit will have only 
firstname:test and lastname:testtwo

how ever if a value is changed for firstname to david than final submit will be 
firstname:david and lastname:testtwo

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="test" />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="test"/>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="testtwo" />

</form>
```

Comment: You CANNOT have 2 elements in your markup with identical IDs

Comment: You use classes for groups of similar elements. IDs are specific to only one element.

Comment: You should use classes. IDs are by definition unique.

Comment: Yo need to asign class to group your elements and ID is only for unique elements.

Comment: @Isac I just fixed the sample code (assuming this is unrelated to the question).

Comment: As @Ryan said, the `id` has to be unique, [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var first_name = $("#firstname").val()
    var last_name = $("#firstname_verification").val()
    
    if(first_name!=last_name){
       console.log("please varify your name")
       // do something here

    } else{
       console.log("name varified")
      // do something here
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="test" />
    <input type="text" id="firstname_verification" value="test"/>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="testtwo" />

</form>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

In addition:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){
    $("form").each(function(){
    var $arr = $(this).find(':input') 
    //get  key/value  pair
    var values = {};
    $arr.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
      console.log(values)
    //get only values  in a single array
    var val_arr = []
    $arr.each(function() {
        val_arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(val_arr)
    //
    if(val_arr[0] === val_arr[1]){
      console.log("name varified")
    } else {
     console.log("please varify your name")
    }
    
     
});
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" name="myform">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="test" />
        <input type="text" id="firstname_verification" value="test"/>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="testtwo" />

    </form>

    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: nice  what if i have 50 fields and need to do comparison on them is there a dynamic way  using for each

Comment: Let me know if you have any concern

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/es9ff4c4/2/

I stated in the initial comments with many others, don't ever use an id for more than one element. In this case, since it is a form we don't need a name for the second box. It's just verifying an element we are already submitting. For an ID I decided to call it, aptly, "firstname_verification"

HTML

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="test" />
    <input type="text" id="firstname_verification" value="test"/>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="testtwo" />

</form>
```

JavaScript/JQuery

```
$("#myform").on("submit", function(e) { 
let $box1val = $("#firstname").val();
let $box2val = $("#firstname_verification").val();

if($box1val != $box2val) {
alert('Please Verify First Name');
e.preventDefault();

 }

});
```

Please see demo here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/es9ff4c4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change your html

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
    <input class="person" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="test" />
    <input class="person" type="text" name="firstname" id="secondname" value="test"/>
    <input class="person" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="testtwo" />

</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var elements = document.getElementByClass('person');

console.log(elements[0].value) // print test.
```